# Best way for making a singleton socket for web application in .net?

Tags: asp.net, .net, web-applications, singleton

I am having a lot of problems with the behaivour of the socket (not closing or opening correctly) used in a webapp to communicate with another program running on a server. The problems I hava found is that the socket either ends up being opened or closed various times during the same request or it does not ends even when I kill the active session.

Currently I save the socket in a Session Variable and I check whenever it should be created or if the value of the variable should be referenced, although I am still having a lot of problems.

Have you faced something similar and would you share some of your experience with me?

Also at first I tried to make it Static although I had even more problems with it.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You put your active open sockets in cache or application object in dictionary or whatever suits you provided by asp.net. Before opening new port you check if it is already open by looking in dictionary stored in application or cache. Remove the entry from dictionary when conection is lost.